# Getting Segmentation fault on aerospike.client.scan.foreach() after select()

Tags: python, aerospike

I have the following code, which is running fine for one aerospike set but throwing following error for

```
import aerospike
import sys,traceback
import redis
import time
import json
import sys

def process_result((key, metadata, record)):
    try:
        print "key" //This is printing for working set
        //Removed all other logic from here. 
    except:
        print("Got errors in processing " + key[2])


columnNames = {0:'PK',1:'merchantInKey'}

client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
scan = client.scan('namespace', 'setname')
#print type(columnNames)
scan.select(**columnNames) 
scan.foreach(process_result)
```

Error -

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have no clue what is wrong in case of this set.

**Update**

Specifying fields like this, instead of `**columnNames` in the above example works -

```
scan.select('PK','merchantInKey')
```

Comment: This is a bug report, not a question about how to write code. Please open it as a new issue at [aerospike/aerospike-client-python](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues), with the necessary details

Comment: Ok, raised a bug.

Comment: By the way, why don't you just use `scan.select('PK','merchantInKey')`, as the API for [`aerospike.Scan.select`](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/scan.html#aerospike.Scan.select) actually suggests you do?

Comment: On further debugging, I found that the issue is due to a particular field, for which both these ways of retrieving are throwing the same error. It seems, this field has some some Java List of DTOs stored. Will update as I get more details.

Comment: Please update https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/issues/224 with that information.